# What's the meaning of domestic transfer?

Tags: meaning

In my bank account I've one voice that is called domestic transfer.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have voices in your bank account? That sounds spooky! ;)
I guess you mean an *in*voice. :)

Well, a transfer is the displacement of something from one place to another.
You can transfer money from one account to another account.

Domestic means that it happens within the country, it is not an international transfer.

So what is mentioned in your bank account statement can be two things: the actual money being transferred from or to your account from another account withing the same country, or, more likely, the *costs* that the bank charges you to process the transfer of money to or from your account.

It is good you mentioned the context though, because my first thought was "domestic transfer" at an airport: domestic transfers are flights that take international travelers who have just arrived to other places in the country.